# Assigning Credit to a specific Service on Azure

Tags: azure, msdn

I get 50$ credit on Azure Services for being an MSDN Subscriber.I have a web app on azure which NEEDS to be online all the time and there are also some other services on Azure whenever My Azure Credits Finishes My azure account is disabled and all my Services are stopped.

Is there a way to make the web app take its credit before itself so that even if the credits finishes,The Web App will still be online?

Comment: credit is for the subscription and not specific to a service. The app service will run as long as the credit is available.

Comment: If you "need" your app to be online anytime, then you might consider a less risky approach than depending on a $50 credit (such as adding a credit card). In any case - off-topic.